# Как обрезать строку в Ruby до определённого символа?

Tags: ruby, строки

Например, есть строка `blablabla?ablablabl`, нужно чтобы в новой строке содержались только символы до знака вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

`str.split(??)[0]`
или
`str[/(.*?)\?/,1]`
или
`str[/.*?(?=\?)/]`

Answer (score 0):

Так:

```
'blablabla?abl?abl?abl'.match(/[a-z]*\?/)[0][0..-2]
```

или так:

```
'blablabla?abl?abl?abl'.split('?')[0]
```

Но, скорее всего, есть более элегантные способы.